# How can I center text / links in CSS on my webpage? (having problems with text-align)

Tags: css

I can't seem to get links to center on my webpage. The code below should theoretically make the links appear in the center but it doesn't:

```css
#navigate2 {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #555555;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*I have included text align but it doesn't seem to be working*/
}

#navigate2:hover {
  background-color: #777777;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo" >
  <h3>Photo &amp; Video</h3>
  <!-- photo goes here -->
  <br> <!-- I want the links labelled navigate 2 to be centered-->
  <a id="navigate2" href="#">Browse my albums!</a>
  <br> <br> <hr>
</div>

<div class="blog">
  <h3>Blog</h3>
  <br> <!-- read above -->
  <a id="navigate2" href="#">Read my blog!</a>
  <br> <br> <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: The are centered... within the `a` tag, but since its inline, the box is only as wide as the text itself which means they aren't centered in the div. Add block level elment to wrap them, or apply the text-align to the existing `div` and change the alignment on the `h3` if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have text-align:center property set to the parent of the anchor tags. Not to the anchor tags

```css
 #navigate2 {
   padding: 10px 20px;
   background-color: #555555;
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
   text-align: center;
   /*I have included text align but it doesn't seem to be working*/
 }
 #navigate2:hover {
   background-color: #777777;
   text-decoration: underline;
 }
 .navigate-wrapper {
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <h3>Photo &amp; Video</h3>
  <!-- photo goes here -->
  <br>
  <!-- I want the links labelled navigate 2 to be centered-->
  <div class='navigate-wrapper'>
    <a id="navigate2" href="#">Browse my albums!</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <hr>
</div>

<div class="blog">
  <h3>Blog</h3>
  <br>
  <!-- read above -->
  <div class='navigate-wrapper'>
    <a id="navigate2" href="#">Read my blog!</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` tags are inline, so centering text in them has no effect.  You could try to add `display: block`,  or instead `display: inline-block;` and `margin: 0 auto` for centering the inline-block.

Comment: which doesn't work without a set width in his example.

Comment: How come they are inline? And I added the code display: block - but that means the gray becomes a bar. The other option doesn't do anything. I've already solved it but just trying to understand your thought process. Edit- should've read the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `id`'s should be unique, give your links a class instead. Secondly, `a` elements are inline, meaning you cannot apply a block level style to it. Instead, specify in your CSS to display it as a block: `display:block;`.